# SSL error: invalid or self signed certificate in Magento 1.9 while uploading a particular file

Tags: magento, ssl

I've had a look, but can't find an answer to this problem already.

I am trying to upload a downloadable product in Magento 1.9. I am getting:

> SSL error: invalid or self signed certificate

This problem is happening for only one file. No problem with images and other files.

The size of file is 2mb, but I can upload a different file that is 3mb, same format in same place and it works fine. I think the problem is not the size or format of the file.

I have uploaded around 45 images and 45 PDF files without this error, but for this particular file I've had this error 50 times.

I have cleared Magento's cached and tried logging out and back in again - no positive result.

I've also tried renaming the file - no joy.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the exact problem. The issue is how I compressed the image. :D